# What's causing this no method error?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Ive prepared this code. Aim is simple -> add a new book and then call the description method which should product "Title is written by author"

But when I run it I get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `set_title_and_author' for #
```

Whats going wrong?

```
class Book
 def set_title_and_author=(title, author)
   @title = title
   @author = author
 end

 def description
   print "#{title} is wrtten by #{author}" 
 end
 end

book = Book.new
book.set_title_and_author("The hunger games", "Larry Page")
book.description
```

Comment: Look at the name of the method you are defining. Look at the name of the method you are calling. Notice the difference.

Answer (score 2):

well you are overriding the = operator, but then not calling it..

```
def set_title_and_author(title, author)
   @title = title
   @author = author
 end
```

is probably what you want.

normally you would use the = method to build a customer attr_writer.  such as

```
  def author=(author)
     @author = author.capitalize
  end
```

or something similar (forced example above)

Comment: Small typo! Thanks for your check answer!